# ¿Como puedo pasar un parametro de una consulta de una API a vue-head?

Tags: vue.js

Estoy pasando el valor de una consulta utilizando el [vue-head](https://github.com/ktquez/vue-head/tree/v1.0.5) para el titulo del navegador pero cuando paso los datos no pasa ningún dato en el encabezado solo me manda un mensaje como **"undefined"** en la parte superior del navegador, este es el codigo:

```
    export default {
      data: () => ({
        video: {}
      }),
      methods: {
        getVideo() {
          this.api.http.get(`videos/${this.videoSlug}`)
            .then(response => {
              this.video = response['data'][0]
            })
        }
      },
  head: {
    title: function() {
      return {
        inner: this.video.name,
        separator: '|',
        complement: 'Canal 10'
      };
    }
  }
}
```

cuando paso el valor de esta forma me manda con "undefined" pero si paso cualquier dato de forma estatica como por ejemplo " **inner: 'Revista'** " lo muestra en el navegador, alguna idea de como puedo solucionar esta situación??

Answer (score 1):

Encuentro algunas inconsistencias en tu código (espero que no lo hayas omitido/borrado para hacer la pregunta).

Primero `videoSlug` no está definido en la data, y por último es necesario que añadas un `console.log(response)` para que puedas ver como es la estructura de la respuesta `response` a tu request.

Adicionalmente podrías mejorar tu código evitando ese indeseable `undefined` añadiendo esto `inner = this.video.name ? this.video.name : 'Titulo por defecto aquí';`

Comment: Hola, un amigo me indico que puedo hacer en este caso se paso con "     .then(response => {
        this.programs = response.data
        this.$emit('updateHead')
    })" con el emit actualize la información de la consulta, Gracias por dar me otra forma de checar